# REST avoid duplication of efforts

Tags: rest

Consider the example scheme below, as you can see a Regiment has a many-to-many relationship with contractors which can be the same for several regiments.

[image]

If I have to create two regiments with several hundreds of common contractors I will basically upload two times the same contractors to the server:

```
<regiments>
<regiment>
      <contractors>
        <conctractor>
        <id>1</id>
        ...
        </contractor>
        <conctractor>
        <id>2</id>
        ...
        </contractor>
      </contractors>
</regiment>
<regiment>
      <contractors>
        <conctractor>
        <id>2</id>
        ...
        </contractor>
        <conctractor>
        <id>5</id>
        ...
        </contractor>
      </contractors>
</regiment>
</regiments>
```

I am using a PUT where regiments and contractors have a predefined ID because I'm using REST to synchronize a desktop application to a web application and both have to use the same IDs for their entities.

Notice the contractor object is very big and has sublists of its own so re-uploading even a single contractor is a big loss of time and resources for the server.

How can I avoid uploading the same contractors over and over?

Comment: Is a contractor addressable as a resource of its own? If yes, you can just reference it in a regiment.

Comment: Yes I can reference a contractor and add it with a REST PUT of its own. However If I have to associate N Regiments with a contractor I will have to upload N Regiments with the conctractor repeated for each. That's the waste I am talking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason you can't use a representation that allows you to link to an existing Contractor which has previously been `PUT`:

```
<regiments>
<regiment>
      <contractors>
        <contractor-ref uri="/contractors/1"/>
        <contractor-ref uri="/contractors/2"/>
      </contractors>
</regiment>
<regiment>
      <contractors>
        <contractor-ref uri="/contractors/2"/>
        <contractor-ref uri="/contractors/5"/>
      </contractors>
</regiment>
</regiments>
```

Comment: How does Jersey for instance serialize and de-serialize those URIs? If you could enrich the answer with some sample code to mange URIs it would be helpful.

Comment: It's going to depend wildly on the server-side technology you're using. It appeared to me that you were asking a conceptual question about REST, not about how to implement such a scheme on the server. If you would like an implementation answer, ask an implementation question please.